# Compiling Windows8 app to other versions

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

If I make a Windows8 App (Javascript template), will I be able to compile it also for Windows Phone 8 and as windowed Windows 7 application?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Or searched for anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

WinJS (or any other format) Metro Store apps do not have a direct equivalent in Windows 7.

For Windows Phone 8 you may be able to reuse some of your business logic but you'll need a new UI layer and the WinJS functionality isn't supported.

Comment: Is there any other Dev tool of framework that will enable me to develop HTML5 apps which will run as standalone software but which will not run in their sandbox, but have full access to file system (Building a file browser)?